# mySql query return if row is equal

Tags: mysql

OK I tried looking through the mySQL threads but I couldn't find what I wanted probably because I didn't know the correct terms.

Anyways I need a query to return rows that are equal to a string. This case "David" I want to show two things "comments" and "postdate". Only the date is being shown right now but no comments. Yes there is data in the comments.

Here is what I have so far:

```
> $query  = "SELECT * FROM sessionscomments  session = 'David'"; 
> $result = mysql_query($query);
> 
> 
> while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
> 
>   echo    "<div id=fav>";     
>   echo    strip_tags( "Date: {$row['postdate']}");
>   echo    "</div>";   
>   echo    "<br>";     
>   echo    strip_tags("{$row['comments']}");
>   echo    "<br>";     
>   echo    "<hr class= \"box\">";
> 
> }
```

and I have the date stored with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP how can I just show the day month and year?

and how can I have the last echo line NOT happen with the last run through?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: General suggestion: Get out of the habit of using `SELECT *` and explicitly list the columns you're returning. If you only need the `postdate` and `comments` columns returned, then only SELECT those. Also looks like your query is missing the WHERE keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called a `WHERE` clause, and you've almost got it in your query:

```
SELECT comments, postdate
FROM sessioncomments
WHERE session='David'
```

Don't use `SELECT *`. It's inefficient, especially if it's a "wide" table and you're only going to use a couple fields. It's like hauling home a month's worth of groceries and then throwing it all in the trash and eating only the jellybeans and cookies.

As well, don't assume a query succeeds. At bare mininum, for developing purposes, you should always do something like this:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This'll kill the script if the query fails, and tell you exactly why it failed. Otherwise your script would simply continue onwards with no (or bad) results and probably screw up later on because of this bad data.

Comment: hey thinks you really helped me out and got me on the right track. thanks so much

Comment: The "*for developing purposes*" can't be stressed enough, nothing screams "come hack me" as outputting raw DB errors on live pages.

Comment: I go out of my way to scream "come hack me"...LOL, thanks for the laugh